# using the lime js html5 game framework with appmobi

Tags: html

Does anyone know how I would incorporate lime js into an appmobi app? It doesn't seem as straight-forward as some other frameworks/engines. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create your games as normal for the desktop.  When you want to plug it in AppMobi, start a blank project and put your game initializing script in the onDeviceReady function (the appMobi.device.ready event listener).

If you have any questions, check out our forums to get quicker support.  http://forums.appmobi.com

Ian